# UICollectionViewController file not implementing a custom protocol

Tags: ios, swift

I have created a protocol in one file and tried to make the `UICollectionViewController` implement it, but its throwing an error of use of undeclared protocol. The same protocol can be implemented on a `UIViewController` class.

Comment: Please show the code for the protocol declaration and for the `UICollectionViewController` declaration.

Comment: Paste code and make sure you have import your protocol file